# Visual Studio Code icons like `tree` in terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know of any VS Code extension for visualizing the folder and files structure with a similar format to the terminal `tree` command? See the image as an example: [image]

Comment: if you can't find one, write it yourself